Best appoach to build Entity Framework Core queries
I am building a .NET app that gets data from Telegram. I am storing Telegram Channels, Topics and Messages in a SQLite database. The structure of the database looks like this:

Basically:

Channels can or can not have many Topics
Channels can have many messages
Topics can have many messages

I want to be able to properly retrieve Channels, Topics and Messages so when I sync from Telegram I don't insert duplicates. I have a few test channels where I have 100s of topics and 10000s of messages and as one would expect, a LINQ call like this is awful
var channels = teleContext.Channels
                          .Include(a => a.Messages)
                          .Include(a => a.Topics).ToList();

Even if I add a Where to that query it is slow (for instance where ChannelID == someVariable). I need to be able to update most columns in Channels, a few in Topics and nearly all in Messages (to ensure data is accurate with Telegram).
Is there a combination of eager loading and split queries that I can implement to make the calls to the DB perform better?

Start from AsSplitQuery(), here you have cartesian explosion of returned records.

AsSplitQuery() will help with reducing the Cartesian Product of a large join set, but in a situation where you have thousands or more child records that you want to append to while detecting duplicates, you might need to get a bit creative in terms of how to compare entries.
If you have 10 messages for a given channel that you want to insert if they aren't already there along with a channel update, then I would consider splitting the operations rather than loading the channel and all messages. You could load the channel alone, update that, then query messages relative to the channel for duplicates before inserting one or more of the 10 new rows.  For instance if messages have a posted date and some other attribute that you use as a first pass to identify possible duplicates:
var startDateTime = newMessages.Min(x => x.MessageDateTime);
var endDateTime = newMessages.Max(x => x.MessageDateTime);

var channel = await context.Channels.SingleAsync(x => x.Id == channelId);
var existingMessages = await context.Messages
    .Where(x => x.Channel.Id == channelId
        && x.MessageDateTime >= startDateTime && x.MessageDateTime <= endDateTime)
    .ToListAsync();

From here you have a range of messages to look more closely at for duplicates or entries to be updated vs. inserted.
You could also opt for a selective eager load in EF Core:
var channel = await context.Channels
    .Include(x => x.Messages
        .Where(m => m.MessageDateTime >= startDateTime && m.MessageDateTime <= endDateTime))
    .AsSplitQuery()
    .SingleAsync(x => x.Id == channelId)

Limit the data retrieved to a subset range to perform the relevant comparisons whether that is by date range or particular identifying columns. Whatever you can to reduce the set to compare against.
Since we are reading and potentially modifying a significant # of rows, if you break it up by Channel then I would recommend either using a DbContextFactory to bound fresh DbContexts per iteration, or call context.ChangeTracker.Clear() between channels to flush the change tracking cache. If we end up loading hundreds of messages (out of tens of thousands) with each channel, performance will gradually slow as we add more messages etc. into the tracking cache as each query sifts through the cache looking for potentially related references to link up.
If you need to do a synchronization of a larger set then you might consider batch inserting the comparison set into a staging table then querying with a join between the inserted set against the current data rather than loading the entire channel (or channels) into memory to perform the comparison. If this process is initiated by a user action then I would also consider having this handed off to a queue where a background job picks up a queue request, processes and updates the status of a job when it completes with a success or failure and any relevant result to provide the user. This can also help prevent these rather heavy requests bogging down the system if triggered by multiple users around the same time.
